# Yahalom Protocol

Tags: public-key, symmetric

Here is the Yahalom Protocol: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahalom_(protocol)

I don't understand how Alice forms the 2 messages sent to Bob in the fourth step? Where does the data come from?

For the first message, I'm guessing it's simply that she is forwarding it to Bob without doing anything to it? I am not so sure how she forms {NB}KAB though.

Answer (score 3):

Alice receives $\{A,K_{AB}\}_{K_{BS}}$ in the third step, which she forwards in the fourth step to Bob.

As for $\{N_B\}_{K_{AB}}$, she learns $K_{AB}$ in the message encrypted under the key for herself and the server from step 3 and she learns $N_B$ in the very same message, so she combines these two to form this message.